# What is the music theory behind substituting the IV chord in a I-IV-V progession in A for a G7 instead of D?

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, blues

The other day I was playing guitar and messing around with adding various embellishments to a blues I-IV-V progression in the key of A. One I particularly enjoyed was substituting the D (IV) chord for a G7. I'd like to understand the theory behind this. Thanks!

Here is a recording:

https://soundcloud.com/seymour-frishberg/g7sub/s-nLxx8

Comment: Hm, the [SoundCloud integration](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) can't seem to work.

Comment: For the question: **Ⅰ** - **Ⅳ** - **Ⅴ** is kind of unidiomatic for blues in the first place.

Comment: "substituting the IV chord ... for a G7 instead of D". Do you mean "substituting G7 for the IV chord D"? or "replacing the IV chord ... by a G7 instead of D"? Laurence Payne seems to have answered on that basis but I think it'd be better if the question title were clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're trying to fit everything into a functional 'cycle of 5ths' system,  IV is actually a substitute for ii, V of V.    ♭VII 'works' because it has two notes in common with ii.

♭VII7?   Well, in a jazz/blues environment, you can add a 7th to just about any chord and it won't sound bad!

There are similarities with the 'backdoor progression' where ♭VII  is used as a substitute for V7.   Again, it works because ♭VII has two notes in common with V7.

But beware of trying to hook EVERY progression onto an underlying functional ii, V, I.  'Giant Steps' took that sort of thing about as far as it could go.

Comment: Ah, so basically the G7 works because it shares notes with Bm and it's okay to make it a 7 because ＪＡＺＺ. Are there any other examples of using the ♭VII in this way or similarly? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh! Or could I also think of that chord as being from a particular mode?

Comment: You can label most things as being from a mode.  Not sure it proves anything much.  It's not in one scale, but it's in another scale.  So?